# Transform an XML to XML using XSLT ( sybase output )

Tags: xml, xslt, transformation

I have the following problem. I am not the greatest expert in XSLT, and what I want to succeed in is to transform an XML from Sybase to the following:

Output of Sybase:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="C:\Users\H50S5OB\Desktop\style.xsl"?>
<root>
<row>
    <Cpty_Id>1</Cpty_Id>
    <SENDER>xxx</SENDER>
    <KUNDE>123</KUNDE>
    <DEPOT>123</DEPOT>
    <ACCOUNT_DEBIT>123</ACCOUNT_DEBIT>
    <ACCOUNT_CREDIT>123</ACCOUNT_CREDIT>
    <CREATED>07.10.2016</CREATED>
    <DEALTYPE>FEES</DEALTYPE>
    <STATEMENT_FROM>30.09.2016</STATEMENT_FROM>
    <STATEMENT_TO>30.09.2016</STATEMENT_TO>
    <BUYSELL>V</BUYSELL>
    <WPNAME>AT0123456789</WPNAME>
    <NOMINAL>1.0</NOMINAL>
    <PRICE>117,155</PRICE>
    <DEAL_STARTDATE>07.10.2016</DEAL_STARTDATE>
    <DEAL_ENDDATE>28.06.2017</DEAL_ENDDATE>
    <FEES_PERCENT>2.5941420000000002</FEES_PERCENT>
    <FEES_AMOUNT>150.0</FEES_AMOUNT>
    <FEES_CREDIT>3.9100000000000001</FEES_CREDIT>
    <FEES>3.9100000000000001</FEES>
</row>
<row>
    <Cpty_Id>1</Cpty_Id>
    <SENDER>xxx</SENDER>
    <KUNDE>123</KUNDE>
    <DEPOT>123</DEPOT>
    <ACCOUNT_DEBIT>123</ACCOUNT_DEBIT>
    <ACCOUNT_CREDIT>123</ACCOUNT_CREDIT>
    <CREATED>07.10.2016</CREATED>
    <DEALTYPE>FEES</DEALTYPE>
    <STATEMENT_FROM>30.09.2016</STATEMENT_FROM>
    <STATEMENT_TO>30.09.2016</STATEMENT_TO>
    <BUYSELL>V</BUYSELL>
    <WPNAME>AT0123456789</WPNAME>
    <NOMINAL>1.0</NOMINAL>
    <PRICE>117,155</PRICE>
    <DEAL_STARTDATE>07.10.2016</DEAL_STARTDATE>
    <DEAL_ENDDATE>28.06.2017</DEAL_ENDDATE>
    <FEES_PERCENT>2.5941420000000002</FEES_PERCENT>
    <FEES_AMOUNT>150.0</FEES_AMOUNT>
    <FEES_CREDIT>3.9100000000000001</FEES_CREDIT>
    <FEES>3.9100000000000001</FEES>
</row>
</root>
```

Output of how I would like to have it
Header remains as it is, Entry section is different

```
   <CONFIRM>
    <Cpty_Id>1</Cpty_Id>
    <SENDER>xxx</SENDER>
    <KUNDE>123</KUNDE>
    <DEPOT>123</DEPOT>
    <ACCOUNT_DEBIT>123</ACCOUNT_DEBIT>
    <ACCOUNT_CREDIT>123</ACCOUNT_CREDIT>
    <CREATED>07.10.2016</CREATED>
    <DEALTYPE>FEES</DEALTYPE>
    <STATEMENT_FROM>30.09.2016</STATEMENT_FROM>
    <STATEMENT_TO>30.09.2016</STATEMENT_TO>
    <ENTRY>
        <BUYSELL>V</BUYSELL>
        <WPNAME>AT0123456789</WPNAME>
        <NOMINAL>1.0</NOMINAL>
        <PRICE>117,155</PRICE>
        <DEAL_STARTDATE>07.10.2016</DEAL_STARTDATE>
        <DEAL_ENDDATE>28.06.2017</DEAL_ENDDATE>
        <FEES_PERCENT>2.5941420000000002</FEES_PERCENT>
        <FEES_AMOUNT>150.0</FEES_AMOUNT>
    </ENTRY>
    <ENTRY>
        <BUYSELL>E</BUYSELL>
        <WPNAME>AT0123456789</WPNAME>
        <NOMINAL>1.0</NOMINAL>
        <PRICE>117,155</PRICE>
        <DEAL_STARTDATE>07.10.2016</DEAL_STARTDATE>
        <DEAL_ENDDATE>28.06.2017</DEAL_ENDDATE>
        <FEES_PERCENT>2.5941420000000002</FEES_PERCENT>
        <FEES_AMOUNT>150.0</FEES_AMOUNT>
    </ENTRY>
    <SUM>
        <FEES_CREDIT>3.9100000000000001</FEES_CREDIT>
        <FEES>3.9100000000000001</FEES>
    </SUM>
   </CONFIRM>
```

This is my XSLT so far ( not very much, I am sorry )

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
    <xsl:stylesheet          version="1.0"xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"xmlns:foo="http://www.foo.org/" xmlns:bar="http://www.bar.org">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
    <body>
    <table border="0">
      <xsl:for-each select="row">
        <SENDER><xsl:value-of select="SENDER"/></SENDER>
        <KUNDE><xsl:value-of select="KUNDE"/></KUNDE>
        <DEPOT><xsl:value-of select="DEPOT"/></DEPOT>
        <ADRESS1><xsl:value-of select="ACCOUNT_DEBIT"/></ADRESS1>
        <ADRESS2><xsl:value-of select="ACCOUNT_DEBIT"/></ADRESS2>
        <ADRESS3><xsl:value-of select="ACCOUNT_DEBIT"/></ADRESS3>
        <ADRESS4><xsl:value-of select="ACCOUNT_DEBIT"/></ADRESS4>
        <ACCOUNT_DEBIT><xsl:value-of select="ACCOUNT_DEBIT"/></ACCOUNT_DEBIT>
        <ACCOUNT_CREDIT><xsl:value-of select="ACCOUNT_CREDIT"/></ACCOUNT_CREDIT>
        <CREATED><xsl:value-of select="CREATED"/></CREATED>
        <DEALTYPE><xsl:value-of select="DEALTYPE"/></DEALTYPE>
        <STATEMENT_FROM><xsl:value-of select="STATEMENT_FROM"/></STATEMENT_FROM>
        <STATEMENT_TO><xsl:value-of select="STATEMENT_TO"/></STATEMENT_TO>
      </xsl:for-each>
      <ENTRY>
      <xsl:element name="BUYSELL">
      <xsl:element name="WPNAME">
       </xsl:element>
    </ENTRY>
    </table>
  </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Maybe, someone can help me achieving what I want.
Thank you very much.

Comment: Using `for-each` is almost a code smell in XSLT. Try using (more) templates instead.

Comment: Are you sure that's how your input looks like? Two (or more) `row` elements, with no single root element above them? -- it's also not clear why your input has two `row`s, but there is only one `ENTRY` in your output.

Comment: Yes, this is how my input looks like - it comes from Sybase and the provide it in this way as it seems. Thanks for the ENTRY output, I forgot to write it down, I edited it.

Comment: If that is your input, it is not XML and cannot be processed by XSLT.

Comment: I put a root - tag at the start, so it should be processed, at least I get no error message in Altova XML Spy

Comment: Take a look at this java project. maybe it automatically does it for you? http://people.eng.unimelb.edu.au/baileyj/xsltgen/XSLTGen.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this as your starting point:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/root">
    <CONFIRM>
        <!-- header -->
        <xsl:for-each select="row[1]">
            <xsl:copy-of select="Cpty_Id | SENDER | KUNDE | DEPOT |ACCOUNT_DEBIT | ACCOUNT_CREDIT | CREATED | DEALTYPE | STATEMENT_FROM | STATEMENT_TO"/>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <!-- entries -->
        <xsl:for-each select="row">
            <ENTRY>
                <xsl:copy-of select="BUYSELL | WPNAME | NOMINAL | PRICE | DEAL_STARTDATE |DEAL_ENDDATE | FEES_PERCENT | FEES_AMOUNT"/>
            </ENTRY>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <!-- footer -->
        <xsl:for-each select="row[1]">
            <SUM>
                <xsl:copy-of select="FEES_CREDIT | FEES "/>
            </SUM>
        </xsl:for-each>
   </CONFIRM>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This assumes all the common data (before and after the `ENTRY` elements) is the same for all `row`s, and can be taken from the first `row`.

I suspect the `SUM` part needs to be something else, but I followed your expected output.

Comment: Thank you very much. This is it what I was looking for the last hours. I always had some ideas of how to get it right but then I always failed because of my lack of knowledge. The SUM part is on the right place and in the end it should be a SUM of one of the tags above, however, this should already be delivered through Sybase - Thank you very much!